# How can I remove text inside brackets in Lua?

Tags: regex, lua, gsub

I have a text like `"Text the I need (extra descriptor) text"` and I want `"Text the I need text"`.

I have tried to use `str:gsub('\([^)]*\)', "")` but for some reason fails to work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
str = str:gsub('%b()', '')
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember these are patterns not regular expressions so you can escape with %.  I have added a leading space on the opening brackets,  but you might want to drop it and then remove double spaces separately.

```
str ="Text the I need (extra descriptor) text (more brackets)"
str = str:gsub(' %(.-%) ','')
print(str)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a different escape character for [Lua's special regex flavor](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1):

```
str:gsub('%([^)]*%)', "")
```

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: Thanks. Usually, escaping regex metacharacters is unnecessary within character classes, but I wasn't certain if Lua would behave as expected. I will remove the second version, then.